# Get parent directory in cshell script

Tags: directory, csh

Hi I'm trying to get parent directory in cshell script but the following code found not working in cshell script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f 
set dir=$PWD
set parentdir="$(dirname "$dir")"
```

Error info:

```
Illegal variable name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(t)csh` only support old form of command substitution:

```
$ set dir=$PWD
$ set parentdir=`dirname "$dir"`
$ printf '%s\n' "$parentdir"
/home
```

---

Scripting with csh is [considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), if you can, switch to other modern shells (Even there, you also want to use modern form of command substitution `$(...)`).

Comment: it's working, great answer

Comment: IMO a better answer would be "use sh, bash, ksh, zsh or anything else but [csh or tcsh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).  Especially don't use it for writing scripts".   Long ago, `csh` has some interactive features that were better than what most other shells had at the time, which made it a reasonable choice as an interactive (but not scripting) shell.  Other shells caught up and surpassed those features decades ago.

Comment: IMO it's well within scope.  Sometimes the right answer is "don't do that, do this instead".

Comment: @cas: Ok, I updated with the suggestion. Next time, feel free to make an editing.

Comment: I would only edit a post to fix a mistake or formatting/grammar/spelling etc - never to make it say what I wanted to say (it annoys the hell out of me when people put words in my mouth, so I'm not going to do that to anyone else) and I wasn't even wanting you to update your answer.  My comments were meant to stand on their own....it started as a reply to the OP saying "great answer".  In one sense, that's correct.  In a broader sense, no.